How do I lay drywall flat if the studs are sunken in in garage conversion?
I am converting a garage to a living space and I want to lay the drywall flush to the studs but the studs are sunken in a few inches on the footings. How do I go about this issue without raising the whole slab so the drywall can go all the way down to the slab?

Picture? Likely battens to push the front of the studs out however far is necessary. Note that having drywall down to the slab might not be ideal for moisture and damage reasons.

When you say sunken, do you mean vertically, or horizontally?

I second not having drywall right on the floor.
No pictures, so guessing there is a bit of a step.
Use 1x2s or 2x2s(or larger) to frame out the studs to 1/2 inch from the step, and start the drywall there.
Depending on your location, the extra depth of studs can be used for extra insulation.
An inch or two concrete with drywall flat to it, can be covered with baseboard.

You can even use pressure treated lumber for the baseboard, if you think there is risk of the floor  being damp.
